# How to get result from Celery Redis Backend in php?

Tags: php, redis, celery, microservices, amqp

The only working library for celery in php is `gjedeer/celery-php` and it doesn't support redis as backend.
https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php/issues/9

Do you have any idea to get results in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misread the ticket: The project did not support redis back in 2013 but added support in 2014 ([comment](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php/issues/9#issuecomment-58489856)). The main readme in the repo you liked also has examples on how to connect to redis.